# Where's this in Gros Morne National Park?

Tags: identify-this, national-parks, newfoundland

[image]

1. Is there a geographical term that fits this scenery?
2. My real estate agent didn't take these pictures, but said they look like Gros Morne. Where exactly?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a similar view from Google Earth (the terrain doesn't look as rugged, but that's the limitation of aerial photography). The viewpoint here is in the valley above [Western Brook Pond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Brook_Pond). This type of geography is typical of fjords (the ones here have been cut off from the sea).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is a photo of the Western Brook Pond Fjord which is indeed in Gros Morne National Park.

The photographer is [Jake Graham](https://twitter.com/jakegrahamphoto), who has taken [many other photos](https://canadaphoto.tours/newfoundland) from this point and offers [backcountry tours](https://jakegraham.photography/newfoundland) so you can take your own.

Beyond the tour he offers, [actually getting there](https://www.newfoundlandlabrador.com/trip-ideas/travel-stories/how-to-get-your-photo-taken-at-the-iconic-western-brook-pond-fjord) involves a moderate to strenuous [day hike](https://www.pc.gc.ca/en/pn-np/nl/grosmorne/activ/experiences/western-brook), or a multi-day hike of the 36 km [Long Range Traverse](https://www.alltrails.com/trail/canada/newfoundland-and-labrador/the-long-range-traverse) hiking trail.